# creating spider plots from org-mode tables

Tags: emacs, gnuplot, org-mode

What would be the easiest way to create a [spider plot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/spiderplot.html) (or radar/star plot) from an org-mode table using `org-plot/gnuplot`?

The [org-plot](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Plot.html) docs suggests it should be possible using a `script:` option but it's not clear to me how the table columns can be converted into arrays in a gnuplot script (using this [example code](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/spiderplot.7.gnu) as a starting point)

The input would look something like this...

```
#+PLOT: title:"spiderplot" set:"output './img/spiderplot.png'" script:"spiderplot.gp"
#+TBLNAME: three-fold
| Array1 | Array2 |  Array3 |
|     15 |     25 |      30 |
|     75 |     25 |      35 |
|     20 |     50 |      55 |
|     43 |     50 |      55 |
|     90 |     75 |      80 |
|     50 |     50 |      25 |
```

and produce an image something like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Ethan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6797953/ethan) answer, org-plot creates a temp file which can be referenced as `$datafile` in the gnuplot script. The `sep` isn't required (as it's set on export) and the png options may need to be set...

```
set spiderplot
set style spiderplot fillstyle transparent solid 0.30 border
set for [i=1:6] paxis i range [0:100]
set for [i=1:6] paxis i label sprintf("Score %d",i)
set paxis 1 tics
set grid spider lt black lw 0.2

set terminal png notransparent truecolor enhanced large

plot for [row=1:6] '$datafile' using 1 every 1::row::row lt 0, newspiderplot, \
     for [row=1:6] '$datafile' using 2 every 1::row::row lt 1, newspiderplot, \
     for [row=1:6] '$datafile' using 3 every 1::row::row lt 2
```

Comment: I am not familiar with "org-mode". The link in your question implies that it is based on the old "gnuplot-mode" for emacs.   So far as I know that has not been maintained for a long time, and predates gnuplot version 5.   It may well be that version 5 features are not supported by either "gnuplot-mode" or "org-mode".  If I'm wrong and either or both of those *are* currently maintained, I would appreciate a link or pointer for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. org-mode is part of emacs and includes a plotting option which requires gnuplot. my issue was finding the right point in the Goldberg Machine...

Comment: org-plot can use either of two gnuplot interfaces that can be installed via https://melpa.org/#/?q=gnuplot

Answer (score 2):

```
set spiderplot
set style spiderplot fillstyle transparent solid 0.30 border
set for [i=1:6] paxis i range [0:100]
set for [i=1:6] paxis i label sprintf("Score %d",i)
set paxis 1 tics
set grid spider lt black lw 0.2

set datafile sep '|'

plot for [row=1:6] 'orgplot.dat' using 2 every 1::row::row lt 1, newspiderplot, \
     for [row=1:6] 'orgplot.dat' using 3 every 1::row::row lt 2, newspiderplot, \
     for [row=1:6] 'orgplot.dat' using 4 every 1::row::row lt 3
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected using gnuplot directly, but if i replace the input file with '$datafile' (as in the org-plot docs) it gives an "End of file during parsing" error when run from emacs...

Comment: What if you replace ‘$datafile’ with $datafile?